# Dynamically generate key with scope value AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have an angular directive which prints a title with key contained in a messages.properties file. I would like to dynamically generate the key by concatenate 'root.'+scope.value + '.title' like this

```
titre="{{ 'flux.' + 'typeFlux' + '.title' }}"
```

The result should be like titre="{{ 'flux.typeFlux.title' }}"

How can i do this in my html file?

Thanks.

Comment: `'root.' + value + '.title'`?

Comment: The value of 'typeFlux' is in the scope and can  change.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. Every variable you use in an angular expression is always evaluated as a scope attribute.

Answer (score 2):

In this instance, you want to use [Object Bracket Notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).  The dynamic portion of the expression is used as an object property reference, like so:

```
{{flux[typeFlux].title}}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/OHK7XqZyv2eKhrOROkqi?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try it tomorrow

Comment: your sample doesn't work for multiple reasons.  Firstly, you can't create an object the way you have tried (i.e. `$scope.flux.webdyn.title = 'Title Webdyn';` won't work to *create* the nested properties).  Secondly, there is no `.` between the object and the property in the HTML (i.e. it's `flux[flux.typeflux].title` in your example, not `flux.[ ...`

Comment: I forked your example to show it working: http://plnkr.co/edit/lBNVqx02jg3bDYTh4MHw?p=preview